# irun, ncverilog does not determine header file

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

irun does not determine define.h file. When I use irun like this

```
irun -f xxx.f
```

I've got a error message like this.

> irun: E.FMUK the type of the file m_def.h could not be determined.

Above file is consist of all `'define xxxx`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [irun does not dertermine define.h file.](http://www.edaboard.com/thread340266.html?s=3c2114e0a47d0ee1ceeb69d66b6b2135#post1451520) where dpaul provides a solution involving setting the default file type extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use irun commnad line option - vlog_ext to add new file extensions to irun. 
Add extensions to the list of built-in, predefined extensions by using a plus sign ( + ) before the list of extensions to add. For example, the following option adds .rtl and .vh.

```
-vlog_ext +.rtl,.vh
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename `m_def.h` to `m_def.vh` (or `m_def.v`).

The `.h` file extension is for C/C++ header files. Verilog header files more often use the `.vh` extension; if not then `.v`. SystemVerilog header files should use `.svh` extension.

Many Verilog/SystemVerilog simulators allow overriding/extending the accepted file extension type. Refer to the manual for the specific simulator. Note that some simulator except C/C++, Verilog, SystemVerilog, VHDL, and others. It is recommended *not* to add the file extension to one language that is already being used by another.

In this case `.h` is already used with C/C++, so don't add `.h` to the allowed Verilog/SystemVerilog file extension. If `.vh` is not supported by default, you may add it to the allowed Verilog file extension list.